# How to find the title of a file that sits in between title tags

Tags: python, string, file, parsing

I have some files that have "TITLE..." then have "JOURNAL..." followed directly afterward. The specific lines are varied and are not static per file. I am trying to pull all of the information that exists between "...TITLE..." and "...JOURNAL...". So far, I am able to only pull the line that contains "TITLE", but for some files, that spills onto the next line.

I deduced that I must use a=line.find("TITLE") and b=line.find("JOURNAL")
then set up a for loop of for i in range(a,b): which displays all of the numerical values of the strings from 698-768, but only displays the number instead of the string. How do I display the string? and how do I then, clean that up to not display "TITLE", "JOURNAL", and the whitespaces in between those two and the text I need? Thanks!

This is the one that displays the single line that "TITLE" exists on

```py
def extract_title():
    f=open("GenBank1.gb","r")
    line=f.readline()
    while line:
        line=f.readline()
        if "TITLE" in line:
            line.strip("TITLE   ")
            print(line)   
    f.close()
extract_title()
```

This the the current block that displays all of thos enumbers in increasing order on seperate lines.

```py
def extract_title():
    f=open("GenBank1.gb","r")
    line=f.read()
    a=line.find("TITLE")
    b=line.find("JOURNAL")
    line.strip()
    f.close()

    if "TITLE" in line and "JOURNAL" in line:
        for i in range(a,b):
            print(i)


extract_title()
```

Currently, I have from 698-768 displayed like:
698
699
700
etc...
I want to first get them like, 698 699 700,
then convert them to their string value
then I want to understand how to strip the white spaces and the "TITLE" and "JOURNAL" values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the loop. just use slicing:

```
line = 'fooTITLEspamJOURNAL'
start = line.find('TITLE') + 5 # 5 is len('TITLE')
end = line.find('JOURNAL')
print(line[start:end])
```

output

```
spam
```

another option is to split

`print(line.split('TITLE')[1].split('JOURNAL')[0])`

`str.split()` returns list. we use indexes to get the element we want.
in slow motion:

```
part2 = line.split('TITLE')[1]
title = part2.split('JOURNAL')[0]
print(title)
```

Comment: Can you explain whats going on in the print statement? I would love to learn how that works :-)

Comment: I edited my answer. And `print` is a function in python3. It was statement in python2.

Comment: I meant what was inside of the print function please

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get what you want to achieve here but if I understood it correctly you have a string similar to this "TITLE 659 JOURNAL" and want to get the value in the middle ? If so you could use the slicing notation as such:

```
line = f.read()
a = line.find("TITLE") + 5 # Because find gives index of the start so we add length
b = line.find("JOURNAL")
value = line[a:b]
value = value.strip() # Strip whitespace
```

If we now were to return value or print it out we get:

```
'659'
```

Similar if you want to get the value after JOURNAL you could use slicing notation again:

```
idx = line.find("JOURNAL") + 7
value = line[idx:] # Start after JOURNAL till end of string
```

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with the strip command. Could you explain how that works? I read the python docs and I'm still confused exactly how it works. Thanks!

Comment: @NickPepin Sure, it only removes whitespace at the very start and end of the string and keeps it inbetween. So if you have a string like " a b c   " it would give you back "a b c".